# Finding shortest path connecting two points under assumption of staying on the "road"?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I search for the name (and later the algorithm ;) ) of the following problem: find the shortest path from point z0 to ze such as the path stays on the "road". The illustration below shows it better. The road is defined by two vectors of points X=(x1,...,xk) and Y=(y1,...,yn). We assume that the problem is not tricky (i.e. paths X, Y do not cross, initial / end points are on the "road", etc.). We want to find red line (defined as a vector) Z being a shortest path connecting z0 with zend and passing only by the road. Algorithm does not need to be fast. Thanks a lot for any hints!

[image]

UPDATE: After the remark I changed the image since it showed wrong solution... :/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remark! Solution on the drawing was wrong. I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've drawn it, your road is a monotone polygon (that is, there's always Y to the left of you, and X to the right of you, when you're facing directly north). Once you've triangulated the polygon there's an algorithm specifically for finding shortest paths in a monotone triangulation, called the "funnel algorithm".

For triangulating the monotone, the description in Mark de Berg's *Computational Geometry* is great, but failing that, http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cot5520/Triangul_monotone.ppt looks pretty good. For the funnel algorithm, try [here](http://ahamnett.blogspot.ie/2012/10/funnel-algorithm.html).

Comment: It might be helpful to copy a bit from "Theory" in the second link you provided, so the answer is a little more self-contained (less dependent on the links).

Comment: Ordinarily I would.. but the web already has too many half-complete descriptions of the funnel algorithm, and enough fully-complete ones that I'm not too worried about link rot.

Comment: I asked [a Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212924/206447) about something very similar not too long ago. The general consensus seems to be that you should still include a brief overview.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is the wrong answer, but I am assuming that x and y coordinates are the contour of the road. If so, why not do the following:

1. Draw a line down the middle of the road (separating traffic),
2. Assume the user is driving on the right side (or left for UK, Australia or Japan).
3. Assuming a single lane, then draw a line in the middle of the right side.
4. This line would be the distance traveled along the road.

If this is a road and you look at the red line in the example, the driver is at times in the emergency lane or curb and other times in oncoming traffic.

Comment: If I understand your solution it is defining a path, but not the shortest path.

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, the shortest path would take you at times into the other lane or curbs. if this is really a road, shouldn't the algorithm model how a car drives along a lane in the correct direction?.

Comment: The question is specifically asking for the shortest path. It's generally not wise post answers based on assumptions in direct contradiction to what's stated in the question. If the question appears to contradict itself, it's best to try to clarify in the comments first. Also note that "road" is written in quotes quite a few times in the question, meaning that it's likely not referring to an actual road.